# OnButtonClick Repeat Specified code at Specific Place

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

The Title explains it well, but for the sake of redundancy. I am trying to make a button click that generates code on the page (defined code of course).

```
protected void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

The code I want it to generate will add 2 drop down lists that will automatically increment by 1 the drop down list ID's it generates, also it needs to create a table in the database based on a SQL query.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" DataSourceID="box_1" DataTextField="box_1" ToolTip="Checkbox #1" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem Text="--Select One--" Value="" />

        </asp:DropDownList>
```

**EDIT**

```
protected void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int a = 0;
        string x = dropdowncounter.Value;

        a = Convert.ToInt16(x);
        a = a + 1;
        dropdowncounter.Value = a.ToString();
        DropDownList DropDownList1 = new DropDownList(){
            // Set the DropDownList's Text and ID properties.
            Text = "DropDownList", 
            ID = "DropDownList" + a.ToString(),
            DataSourceID = "Box_1",
            DataTextField = "box_1",
            ToolTip = "Check Box Added!"
        };
        //addoptions1 = DropDownList1;
        //addoptions.Controls.Add(myDropDownList);
        //// Add a spacer in the form of an HTML <br /> element.
        //addoptions.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));



    }
```

This is what I have so far, I feel like I'm close to what I need functionality wise (although I'm not seeing any new Drop Down boxes being made.). Any help?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what's your question. Do you want the code in AddButton_Click() method?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I want, I want it to execute when the button is clicked (went ahead and included it in the post) @JakeLin

Comment: You can try using a **for** loop or a button.PerformClick().

Comment: I'm not familiar with the **for** loop call. What does it do and how would it fit in what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Could you please me more specific?? You have a button and inside the click event what action do you want to perform??

Comment: I want it to generate a New asp:DropDownList with a specific ID and the list needs to be populated by a table (it needs to be created when they click the button).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int count = DropDownList.Items.Count + 1;
    DropDownList.Items.Add(count.ToString(),count.ToString());
}
```

Is it what you want?

Comment: I think that's part of it. I need to figure out how to get it to make more drop down lists on the page that populate based on a table that gets created when it is created.

Comment: @Apezdr That's a big topic, you can use ADO.net, Entity Framework or Linq to SQL. Please google these key words, and found the sample code you need. Here is one. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/936d779d-a987-400b-a2e2-525d6b7edf04/how-to-fetch-the-data-from-sql-server-using-c

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(s);
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select FieldName from TableName", con);
 SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 sda.Fill(ds);
 DropDownList1.DataSource = ds;
 DropDownList1.DataTextField = "FieldName";                          
 DropDownList1.DataValueField = "FieldName";
 DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

Comment: So what does this code do? I see that it can look for a field in a table, then after SqlDataAdapter I lose it. I'm not familiar with this "DataSet" either. Some insight into what this does will help me tell you if this is what I need or not. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: The above code is related to taking data from the database and displaying it in dropdownlist.